# What domain names are served by a host?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx

For a set of VPSes operated by my company, I'd like to get a list of domain names hosted by each. The list of names has grown in an ad-hoc way for a few years. Is there a simple way to query the Apache and/or Nginx configurations to see what domains the server answers to on port 80?

It is safe to assume (a) that I have sudo on these systems, and (b) they aren't using wildcards, although a solution which acknowledged that a wildcard was in use would be useful too if it also provided a list of explicit domains.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see two possible ways.
First:

```
egrep '(ServerName|ServerAlias)' /path/to/httpd/conf/vhosts/* | uniq
```

Second:

```
dig @8.8.8.8 4.3.2.1.in-addr.arpa PTR
```

Here 1.2.3.4 is your server's external IP. Of course, this will do the trick if PTR records were maintained together with A records.

Or I missed something in your question?..

Comment: Your first suggestion works best; the second doesn't, I think possibly because PTR records weren't maintained. The grep pattern will need modifying for Nginx but that shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: I'm not an nginx expert, but I see "server_name" in nginx.conf

Comment: I think you're right, that string is all I'll need; Nginx doesn't distinguish between the ServerName and ServerAlias like Apache does, it just takes a list of names.

Answer (score 2):

```
apache2ctl -S
```

Will print out virtual hosts for apache, but I don't know how to get this in nginx.

Comment: This is great, it lists all virtual hosts with ServerName, but doesn't include the ServerAliases.